# Rails: pass variable from the view to stylesheet

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I render a partial in my view:

```
<section class="about map">
<h3>Contact address</h3>
<div id="gmap">
</div>
<% content_for :address_slider_top, 50 %>
<% content_for :address_slider_left, 80 %>
<%= render partial: 'address_slider' %>
</section>
```

I would like to set the values **address_slider_top** and **address_slider_left** so I can decide from the view the position of my partial "address_slider" in my css.erb

```
#addresses{
width: 300px;
background-color: #fff;
height: 400px;
margin-top: <%= yield(:address_slider_top).to_s %>px;
margin-left: <%= yield(:address_slider_left).to_s  %>px;
}
```

It gives me a LocalJumpError. 
I tried with

```
<%= render partial: "address_slider", locals: {address_slider_top: 50, address_slider_left: 80} %>
```

But I could not make it work either.

Comment: Yeah, assets are treated differently, unlike views. In production they are precompiled and never change. Bypassing this will be... not too simple. The easiest (not the best though) solution would be CSS in `<style>` in a corresponding view.

Comment: Thanks, so the best solution in my case is just to encapsule in a div wrapper:
<div class="wrapper" style="margin-top: 50px;margin-left: 80px;">
    <%= render partial: 'address_slider' %>
</div>

Comment: I never thought you'd actually use it... Fine then. I'll write an answer that explains the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assets are not views. Sure they are treated similarly by HTTP, but they are not similar in nature and serve different purposes.

Most of the time assets have an interesting property: they are static, **they never change**. Views, on the other hand, are a representation of data and often change.

So, Rails has an **asset pipeline** that exploits that staticness. In development, assets are kept large for ease of debugging and recompiled on every change. In production, however, there is a special task `rake assets:precompile` that compiles assets into the `public` folder which is then typically served by a reverse proxy like **nginx** that does it fast.

So your best bet for embedding variables in your assets is **rendering the styles in question inside a view**. It might be written inline with HTML, it might be a specific view that renders CSS (but I've never seen anyone actually do this).

Comment: Thanks D-side, you have been very helpful.